# Why is the server response time slowing my site down?

Tags: performance, server, shared-hosting, dns

My site is www.phoenixwave.com

When I use Pingdom speed test and Google's speed test both give me the conclusion that my server response time is ridiculously slow...I'm using a Rackspace server.

I'm just trying to get a general direction where I need to start troubleshooting. Should I look into different hosting? Am I having a server problem or a DNS problem?

Thanks for any and all help provided from the community.

See the result picture from Pingdom below:
[image: Pingdom Test of Phoenixwave.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clearly isn't a DNS problem since "wait time" is counted after domain was resolved and connection to server has been established.

What you can start with on WordPress level is getting a plugin which will show you is this time is actually spent inside WP page load.

[Laps](https://github.com/Rarst/laps) (disclosure — developed by me) or [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) are what I look at first for issues like this.